# Jquery isEmptyObject returns true even though it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the jquery code i am using

```
console.log(arrayPgggoData[taxonomy]);
console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(arrayPgggoData[taxonomy]));
```

And I don't know why it is returning true.

[image]

Also, what I am actually trying to see if the key inside is not an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation clearly states:

> The argument **should always be a plain JavaScript Object** as other types of object (DOM elements, primitive strings/numbers, host objects) may not give consistent results across browsers. To determine if an object is a plain JavaScript object, use **$.isPlainObject()**

But you are checking over an array.

To check if an array has no elements, you can simply rely on its `.length` property.

```
arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].length === 0
```

If you have some array values that you want to consider as "empty" values, then `.filter` method is your friend.

```
nonEmptyValues = arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].filter(function(el) { return el !== '' })
```

**ES6 friendly syntax**

```
const nonEmptyValues = arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].filter(el => el !== '')
```

Comment: thank you `arrayPgggoData[taxonomy].length` this does not work because if the array above has an empty string element "". so it gives me a length = 1 even if it empty . any work around?

Comment: @GeekyOwl For that purpose, use array filter method.